# How to modify only input variable so that awk command will escape the space in the varibale in linux?

Tags: linux, awk

I have password.txt and it only contains 1 line : instance user pass word

I execute read_pass.ksh to get password. script is as below:

```
instance=${1}
userid=${2}
password=$(grep -iw "${instance}" "./password.txt"|grep -iw 
"${userid}"|awk '{print $3}')
echo $password
```

After I ran "ksh read_pass.ksh instance user", it returns me only "pass" not "pass word".

How can I modify password.txt only to help awk escape the space in "pass word"? Note: I can't modify the script because it is one piece of production code. Thank you very much.

I have modified "instance user pass word" into "instance user pass\ word" or "instance user pass\\ word" or "instance user pass'\'' word", etc.

I expect to get below output:
pass word

Comment: `awk` does not interpret escapes in text input. The awk statement says "get the third whitespace separated field", and there's nothing the input data can do to change that. If you can't fix the script, consider changing the user's password

Comment: replace the space in the 'password' field with a character(s) that you don't expect to show up in the 'password' field (impossible if password can contain 'any' character?), then re-insert the space afterwards; eg, 'myinstance myuser my password' becomes 'myinstance myuser my%20password', run through script and get 'my%20password' as output, now replace '%20' with space to give you 'my password'; but I'd probably want to look at creating/using my own script (assuming the current script cannot be updated/modified)